# Glut Game, custom loop = glutTimerFunc?

Tags: c++, glut

I'm modifying an existing application in C++ that uses GLUT (so I can't get rid of GLUT, which seems to be the consensus). I'm trying to make it into a game-like thing so I want to add stuff to the loop. It seems that the way to do this is to use `glutTimerFunc()`, is that correct? (I can't find all that much information on it).

Comment: What sort of loop are you looking at? I doubt if GLUT has anything to offer if you are looking for a game-loop kind of thing; its event-driven. You will have to modify the code/logic and achieve it using functions that glut calls back.

Comment: The consensus is a consensus for a good reason. Spend the time required to get rid of GLUT - it will hamstring you for serious application development.

Comment: Sadly the professor that wrote the application and will be grading my modifactions doesn't agree with you :)

Comment: @Tessa, that would be good info to include in the question itself.  Also, can you be more specific about what the program currently does and what you're assigned to make it do?  Perhaps you could include a pseudocode outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice link that describes the glut callbacks, what they do, and what the parameters are: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node113.html

I haven't worked on a glut application for a few years, but from what I remember, I used glutTimerFunc to call my game update logic as you suggested.